# Steps to add a new resolution 1366x768 @ 60 (Troubleshooting)

Tags: intel-graphics, display-resolution

I've just installed Ubuntu MATE 18.04 on a laptop and have a dual monitor setup, both displays worked out of the box and the native display even went off on boot. I now need to use 1366x768 resolution on one of the displays but it is not an option. I've added a resolution but the resulting resolution is not correct I accidentally added 1368x768

Trying again gives error:

```
cvt 1366 768 60
sudo xrandr --newmode "1366x768_60.00"  85.25  1366 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a new mode to an output requires several commands in sequence, like so:

```
# create and name a new mode: "1366x768-0"
xrandr --newmode "1366x768-0" 75.61  1366 1406 1438 1574  768 771 777 800 -hsync -vsync

# attach the new mode to an output (VGA1)
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1366x768-0"

# turn on the output using the new mode
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1366x768-0"
```

The reason for the error messages in the question is mode parameters cannot be changed.  Use a new name (such as "1366x768-1") or remove the added mode.  The sequence of commands to remove a mode follow:

```
# turn off the output
xrandr --output VGA1 --off

# detach the mode from the output
xrandr --delmode VGA1 "1366x768-0"

# remove the mode
xrandr --rmmode "1366x768-0"
```

Changes to `xrandr` don't survive reboot.  To make settings persist, ubstitute parameters as appropriate for your setup and save into a script in `/usr/local/bin` and add it to <kbd>Startup Applications</kbd>.  Then it will be run every time you log in.  You might like to [add it at boot up](https://askubuntu.com/a/719157/344926), rather than login.

Comment: Upvoted yesterday, edited today as you forgot to add how to do it automatically.  **;-)**

Comment: How would I add to the script to also turn off my other display plugged with HDMI?