# Is it possible to use Nvidia GUI to set a custom resolution?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution

I have tried and failed to use xrandr to set up my custom resolution of 1366x768 (it throws an error regarding the colour, it seems that there have been reports saying thai this is a problem inherent in Nvidia drivers, in my case 470 and later 510 with a GTX 1050 GPU installed in the machine). Is it possible to use the X Server GUI to set the resolution, if it is - how?

(Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: The native resolution of the display is, according to the spec sheet, 1366x768.

Comment: I doubt that your 1366x768 supports 1366x767 resolution. Why would you want this? Are you sure this isn't an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?

Comment: I apologize - the "767" was a typo, I meant to write 768 as per native resolution. I have tried to do a number of things pertaining to the issue based on a few posts, namely:

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524595/cvt-is-acting-strange-when-defining-resoluton & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028868/steps-to-add-a-new-resolution-1366x768-60-troubleshooting . I have simply gotten annoyed with trying to find a fix, and am trying to see whether I might have somehow missed an exceptionally simple solution. Perhaps I might just use 1280x768 with an underscan.